# Parameters: [unauthRoleName] must have values

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to deploy my data model for a react native App on AWS amplify. After creating my model and importing my custom Auth from the cognito user pool i created Ealier. but i keep getting this error "Parameters: [unauthRoleName] must have values." on deployment. Please How do I solve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing it from Amplify Studio?

I faced a similar problem for my React.js project while doing it from Amplify Studio. But using Amplify CLI from the root folder of the project, I could deploy it.

Pro Tip:
In case you have copied the project to a new location/machine,
run `amplify configure` and `amplify init` again to ensure there is no
`team-provider-info.json does not exist` error

Comment: too many issues using amplify, I will be asking my Boss whether we should go forward with amplify. If we want to modify something then amplify gets into this wierd state

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue. I Ctrl+F the "unauthRoleName" in my amplify project and found out there were some that started with lowercase and some with uppercase and then changing those with lowercase to uppercase fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue.

Here's what helped:

1. Remove the identity pools
2. Unlink the authentication from Amplify
3. Create a new identity pool and link the user pool with the identity pool
4. Link back the authentication to amplify
5. This might break the Amplify studio interface. To fix that, simply disable and then enable the amplify studio

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! (though I didn't have to remove the identity pool, just unlinked it from the app).  Here are some instructions on how to link an identity pool to a user pool: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html